# Encoding=ASCII; and Encoding=UNICODE; do not work in an Npgsql 3 connection string

Tags: windows, postgresql, utf-8, npgsql

I have a new install of PostgreSQL  (9.6.1) using the Big SQL installer, and a new install of Npgsql (3.2.0) using the .msi installer, but non-ASCII character support seems to be broken.

My connection string is:

```
<add name="Northwind" connectionString="Database=Northwind;Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=123;Encoding=ASCII;" providerName="Npgsql"/>
```

I get exception messages like this, when reading back non-ASCII character data:

```
System.Text.DecoderFallbackException : Unable to translate bytes [C3] at index 22 from specified code page to Unicode.
```

I have tried using `Encoding=UNICODE;` instead, but neither works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an old Npgsql connection string. `Encoding=ASCII` or `Encoding=UNICODE` will no longer work when using current (3.2.0) Npgsql to access current (9.6.1) PostgreSQL.

Solution: just remove `Encoding=xxx` completely and everything works!

You don't need to 'fix' your Postgres encodings and locales, you don't need to try to find a working `Encoding` value to use in the connection string; Ngpsql 3 just works with no `Encoding` setting, against the default Postgres install settings on Windows (`Encoding=UTF8 | Collate=English_United Kingdom.1252 | Ctype=English_United Kingdom.1252`) (for UK, but I believe the same thing applies for `English_United States.1252` for US, and other locales).

(See: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1396)